# ActiveRecord, PostgreSQL: group_by and order in the same query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Been trying to get the right query for a little while now. Here's the issue:

1. `User` *has_many* `:connections`
2. `Connection` *belongs_to* `:channel`
3. `Connection` *belongs_to* `:user`

I'm trying to get the channels from the most recent connections that are unique by `channel_id`. I've gotten close with:

```
Connection.includes(:channel).select('DISTINCT on (channel_id) *').where(user_id: u.id).limit(5).collect(&:channel)
```

But when I throw an `order` in there:

```
Connection.includes(:channel).select('DISTINCT on (channel_id) *, created_at').order('created_at DESC').where(user_id: u.id).limit(5).collect(&:channel)
```

I get: `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the channels id auto_increment, and the created_at set by default in the system?

Comment: Yes, channel_id is auto increment and created_at is set by default

Comment: in that case, sorting by `channel_id`, and sorting by `created_at` should result in the same order. so try `Connection.includes(:channel).select('DISTINCT on (channel_id) *, created_at').order('channel_id DESC').where(user_id: u.id).limit(5).collect(&:channel)`

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood... `Channels` can be created independently of `Connections` (and their ids are auto_increment). I could also theoretically make a connection to a `Channel` that is old (and has a low `channel_id` and that `Connection` would still be considered recent.